# Preserving original paragraphs in a generated PDF

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

After lot of tries, I am not able to generate a pdf respecting original paragraphs or loaded text from 'SOME_PARAGRAPHS' path.

Any hints will be very appreciatted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" doctype-public="-//big.faceless.org//report" />
    <xsl:template match="INFORMEMEDICO">
        <pdf>
            <head>
            </head>
            
            <body size="A4" header-height="15mm" footer-height="15mm">

                <br/>
                
                <!-- A (not show) -->
                <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve"><xsl:value-of select="SOME_PARAGRAPHS"/></fo:block>
            
                <br/>
            
                <!-- B (show but without respecting original paragraphs) -->
                <p><xsl:value-of select="SOME_PARAGRAPHS"/></p>                         
            
                <pbr/>          
            
            </body>
        </pdf>                          
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... having:

```
<SOME_PARAGRAPHS>
                Candy cookie topping cotton candy icing pastry tart danish dessert. 

                Icing carrot cake gingerbread candy powder muffin soufflé fruitcake sweet roll.

                Wafer toffee topping jelly-o sesame snaps oat cake pie marzipan lemon drops.
</SOME_PARAGRAPHS>
```

Here simplified version without 'SOME_PARAGRAPHS' participation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"
        doctype-public="-//big.faceless.org//report" />
    <xsl:template match="INFORMEMEDICO">
        <pdf>
            <head>
            </head>
            
            <body size="A4" header-height="15mm" footer-height="15mm">

                <br/>
                
                <!-- (not show) -->
                <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
                    Candy cookie topping cotton candy icing pastry tart danish dessert. 

                    Icing carrot cake gingerbread candy powder muffin soufflé fruitcake sweet roll.

                    Wafer toffee topping jelly-o sesame snaps oat cake pie marzipan lemon drops.                
                </fo:block>
            
                <br/>
                        
                <pbr/>          
            
            </body>
        </pdf>                          
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Although you have used the tag for XSL-FO, your target format seems to be different and based on an unknown report-1.1.dtd and perhaps a proprietary conversion tool. So that way it is hard to tell whether XSL-FO settings make any sense or would be taken into account at all. Also, in the input format where you have an element named `SOME_PARAGRAPHS`, is that an element with plain text content or with some structured XML content like child elements representing a single paragraph?

Comment: Edited to remove that dtd. Behind SOME PARAGRAPHS are 3 simple lines of plain text separated by a carriage return. Thanks

Comment: If SOME_PARAGRAPHS is a direct child of INFORMEMEDICO your example: <!-- A (not show) --> should work.
Could you explain the meaning of your used <pdf> <head> and <body> tags. As @MartinHonnen is mentioning it's not how xsl-fo is meant to be used.

Comment: This is legacy code that from what I've found out uses a library called 'bforeport.jar'. I have contacted their support service to see if they can give me any indication.

Comment: BFO is big faceless formatter. You should be outputting  <pre> tag as it is HTML input to Pdf and not using XSL FO

Comment: If I use <pre> it doesn't work either. A long line is displayed with text that is lost to the right of the pdf

Answer (score 0):

in stead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="SOME_PARAGRAPHS"/>
```

You probably want:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="SOME_PARAGRAPHS"/>
```

And then you need templates that handle those `SOME_PARAGRAPHS` like

```
  <xsl:template match="SOME_PARAGRAPHS">
    <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>
```

I advise to start with an [xsl intro](https://www.data2type.de/en/xml-xslt-xslfo/xslt/xslt-introduction)

And if you are familiar with xsl do a [intro xsl-fo](https://www.data2type.de/en/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/xsl-fo-introduction/quickstart)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation links. (Propossed solution doesnt works. Or I didnt know how to compose it)

Comment: Please share the source in your question, because now I just assumed SOME_PARAGRAPHS were p.

Comment: Sorry , I was not clear, I ment your XML-source

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve it by decomposing the paragraphs in the Java backend:

```
StringTokenizer textoDictamenVidaLineas = new StringTokenizer(textoDictamenVida, "\n");
String linea;
while (textoDictamenVidaLineas.hasMoreTokens()) {
    linea = textoDictamenVidaLineas.nextToken();
    documentoXML.append("<SOME_PARAGRAPHS>" + linea + "</SOME_PARAGRAPHS>\n");
}
```

And using this in the template:

```
<xsl:for-each select="SOME_PARAGRAPHS">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```